# How to increment or decrements the textbox value that is being repeated in loop using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a text box :

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="x in checkoutData">
   <img src="img/minus.jpg" ng-click="Decrement();">
   <input value="1"  type="text" ng-model="items[$index]"/>
    <img src="img/plus.jpg" ng-click="Increment($index);">
 </div>
 </div>
```

My angular code is :

```
$scope.Increment = function(index) {
   alert($scope.items[index]); // TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
};
```

Since the textbox and images are repeating. If I hit particular image only particular textbox value has to be increment also decrement vice versa. How I do that using Angular JS.?

Comment: You should defined separate `model` for each input. like `<input value="1"  type="text" ng-model="x.values"`

Comment: Try changing your ng-model like x.value. Now all your inputs are binded to the same ng-model value

Comment: @Vivz value will remain same 1 for all textbox..

Comment: you can use `$index` to keep track of the index resulting from the ng-repeat, if your case is simple (see [this link](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angular-best-practices-ng-repeats-index) for cases where it can fail). A cleaner way would be to use what's in `x`

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: i would say that `items` should be declared as an `array` in the scope, not sure at this point, and no time to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$scope.items` hasn't been initialized by the time you are trying to increment the counter. Inside the `Increment` function, add a `null`/`undefined` check and set the value to `0`

```
  $scope.Increment = function(index) {
    if(!$scope.items[index]) {
      $scope.items[index] = 0;
    }
    $scope.items[index]++;
  };
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zO39IwIxgua0PTvgIGGK?p=preview)